# React: 'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, types

I am trying to figure out how to solve the problem identified below.

```
'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<{}, any, any> | null' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<{}, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
      Type 'Component<{}, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("...filepath.../node_modules/@types/react-transition-group/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

My react (next) app has _app.tsx as follows:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client"
import { theme } from "@boilerplate/theme"
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import type { NextPage } from "next"
import type { AppProps } from "next/app"
import Head from "next/head"

import { useApollo } from "lib/apollo/client"

type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
  getLayout?: (page: React.ReactElement) => React.ReactNode
}

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout
}

export default function BoilerplateApp(props: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props
  const apolloClient = useApollo(pageProps.initialApolloState)
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page)
  
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      </Head>
      <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
        <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>{getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}</ApolloProvider>
      </ChakraProvider>
      
    </>
  )
}
```

Posts identifying solutions to this problem suggest having the content of the return statement inside a fragment (which I do, and reinstalling node modules (which I have done).

I can't make the error go away and I do not understand what the language of the error message is trying to communicate.

Comment: `"'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component.` -- is this "Component" the  "BoilerPlateApp"? It's not clear where this is being thrown.

Comment: Yes - the terminal error message points to this component

Comment: Oh, I see "Component" is being passed as a prop. That's strange. What happens if you change `getLayout?: (page: React.ReactElement) => React.ReactNode` to `getLayout?: (page: React.ReactElement) => JSX.Element`?

Comment: The solution for me was to update 2 npm packages to version ^18: `@types/react @types/react-dom` -- it seems this has been fixed in react 18. I would add this as an Answer, but try it out first.